# Trying to upgrade / compile old C++ source (from a vendor) - problem with "std::runtime_error"

Tags: c++, std, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to compile some sample code from a product we use.  I don't think the vendor has maintained the code.  I'm using VS Pro 2022 Ver 17.7.5
Here's the snipped of code and the errors it generates.  I haven't used C++ or Visual Studio for 15 years.  Everything is way more complicated and obscure that I recall.
I'm trying to fix the "runtime_error" problem on line #17.  I can't understand [the documentation for that](https://en.cppreerence.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).  I've tried shotgunning it by putting parens around stuff in line 17 to no avail.

```
/* ReadDynaRecordListWithWhere.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    The purpose of this example is to show how to define a dynamic query and read only
    requested column data from the TeamTrack database. This example shows how to request
    information about the users who are members of the "Everyone" group in TeamTrack.
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <new.h>
#include "TSServer.h"
#include "TSDynaRecordList.h"

// Create these before we start because when a memory allocation
// fails it will bee too late (no memory to create new stuff).
static const char * memoryMessage = "Memory allocation failed.";
#ifdef WIN32
static const std::runtime_error bad_alloc( memoryMessage );  // *** Line #17

// Define a function to be called if new fails to allocate memory.
int TSNewHandler( size_t size )
{
  printf( "Throwing: %s\n", memoryMessage );
  throw bad_alloc;                                           // *** Line #23
  return NULL;
}
#endif
```

Error list:

```
Severity  Code   Description                                                                    Line
Error     C2039  'runtime_error': is not a member of 'std'                                      17    
Message          see declaration of 'std'                                                       25    
Error     C4430  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   17    
Error     C2146  syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'bad_alloc'                        17    
Error     C4430  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   17    
Error     C2040  'memoryMessage': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'    17    
Error     C2065  'bad_alloc': undeclared identifier                                             23
```

Comment: The code doesn't include the [correct header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error). Sometimes you can get away with it; other times you can't. Aside: `<new.h>` is highly suspect. It's not a standard header. It could well be pre-standard code, in which case you've got a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: Looks like an include is missing : `#include <stdexcept>`.

Comment: Fix `#include`... -> `<stdexcept>`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error so proper include is: `#include <new>` and `#include <stdexcept>`. This is wrong: `throw bad_alloc;` it should be `throw std::bad_alloc();` or since C++11 `throw std::bad_alloc{};`. Note missing `std::`.

Comment: @MarekR The `bad_alloc` without parentheses looks correct. They have a global variable by that name, and this just throws a copy of that value.

Comment: whole idea of having handler of failed new is pre-standard and sound like trouble... existence of new.h in code may suggest that codebase is literally not fit fir modern compilerwithout careful refactoring.  Although modern new contains a no-throw overload, it behaves differently -it return null if able. bad_alloc may suffer from namespace contamination - there is already `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: If the problem has been solved, you could summarize the solution into an answer and   accept it to change its status to Answered.   Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT -- Done!  I couldn't accept the answer when I entered it.  I forgot to return after 24 hrs and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

---

**Edit 2023-11-05**:

I added "`#include <stdexcept>`" as per @PeteBecker, @PepijnKramer and @Jarod42.  *That eliminated the errors*.  Many thanks to the responders!

Although the "new" didn't seem to be causing problems, I made the changes as outlined by @MarekR.  Those changes did not induce any new problems so they will remain inplace.